# New title on old page - search results show old title

Tags: search, 7

I have a page that used to have 2010-2012 in the title, now it has 2014-2017. When I search for that page using HUD or HUD Grant, I want the new title to show. How can I do that?

Comment: What is HUD in this context? Is it a Drupal component?

Comment: Has cron run in between the update and your search for the content?  It could be as simple as a stale search index.